# Excel OleDbCommand SELECT * does not select all columns

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I download an XLS spreadsheet and I am trying to import it into a .net dataTable. The structure of the sheet is as follows:

(A date column that has no name), Inflow (kWh), Outflow (kWh), Stock (kWh)

ConnectionString is:

```
" Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=sheet.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;IMEX = 1"
```

Things that don't work:

```
- "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" selects: NoName, Inflow_(kWh), Outflow_(kWh) and the last column is missing

- "SELECT [Stock (kWh)] FROM [Sheet1$]" returns: "No value given for one or more required parameters."

- "SELECT [Stock_(kWh)] FROM [Sheet1$]" returns: "No value given for one or more required parameters."

- "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:D]" Selects: NoName, Inflow_(kWh), Outflow_(kWh) and the last column is missing
```

Things that work but are not a solution:

```
- "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$D:D]" Selects: Stock_(kWh) but all other columns are missing
```

- If I open the file in Excel (without saving it) after I downloaded it and then try to import it then it works.
- Excel interop works

Any ideas? Anyone?

Comment: My ConnectionString is :" Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=sheet.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;IMEX = 1" (adding or removing IMEX does not change anything)

Comment: look at this guys question and look at the connection string portion [StackOverFlow OleDbCommand Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637474/sqlbulkcopy-from-excel-via-ace-oledb-truncates-text-to-255-chars)

Comment: Unfortunately changing the connectionstring to "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=sheet.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;" did not have any effect

Answer (score 0):

This is a connection string I use in one of my applications and everything works fine when I use SELECT * FROM [worksheetName$]

```
string connString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='{0}';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1\""
```

It looks very similar to yours, except I have single quotes around the Data Source, and I'm escaping my double quotes (assuming you are doing that properly too but just didn't show it).  So I don't think connection string is your problem.

When you select D:D to get just the missing Stock column, what data type is it?  If you look at the metadata using GetOleDbSchemaTable, what does it show for columns for that table, and the data type of the missing column?

Can you give us a few example rows from your spreadsheet so we can see what the data would look like, and maybe try it out?  Also, it is an XLS, not XLSX right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Follow the download link to get the file: http://www.vattenfall.com/en/usage-of-gas-storage-.htm The format is XLS (not XML based) and the datatype of all columns (including the missing one) is string. The olny difference I see between the columns is that the last one is nullable. Can you reproduce the error?  If I open the file in excel then it fixes the problem (unless I make the file read-only). What does excel do to the file when I open it?